# Tcl / Expect script driven by name pipe blocks/buffers output unexpectedly

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to write an expect script that reacts to input from reading a pipe. Consider this example in file "contoller.sh":

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn bash --noprofile --norc

set timeout 3
set success 0
send "PS1='Prompt: '\r"
expect {
  "Prompt: " { set success 1 }
}
if { $success != 1 } { exit 1 }

proc do { cmd } {
  puts "Got command: $cmd"
  set success 0
  set timeout 3
  send "$cmd\r"
  expect {
    "Prompt: " { set success 1 }
  }
  if { $success != 1 } { puts "oops" }
}

set cpipe [open "$::env(CMDPIPE)" r]
fconfigure $cpipe -blocking 0
proc read_command {} {
  global cpipe
  if {[gets $cpipe cmd] < 0} {
    close $cpipe
    set cpipe [open "$::env(CMDPIPE)" r]
    fconfigure $cpipe -blocking 0
    fileevent $cpipe readable read_command
  } else {
    if { $cmd == "exit" } {
      exp_close
      exp_wait
      exit 0
    } elseif { $cmd == "ls" } {
      do ls
    } elseif { $cmd == "pwd" } {
      do pwd
    }
  }
}

fileevent $cpipe readable read_command
vwait forever;
```

Suppose you do:

```
export CMDPIPE=~/.cmdpipe
mkfifo $CMDPIPE
./controller.sh
```

Now, from another terminal try:

```
export CMDPIPE=~/.cmdpipe
echo ls >> ${CMDPIPE}
echo pwd >> ${CMDPIPE}
```

In the first terminal the "Got command: ls/pwd" lines are printed immediately as soon as you press enter on each echo command, but there is no output from the spawned bash shell (no file listing and current directory). Now, try it once more:

```
echo ls >> ${CMDPIPE}
```

Suddenly output from the first two commands appears but 3rd command (second ls) is not visible. Keep going and you will notice that there is a "lag" in displayed output which seems to be "buffered" and then dumped at once later.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

So, in the proc `read_command`, it's blocking on `set cpipe [open "$::env(CMDPIPE)" r]` and does not get the chance to display the spawned process's output until you `echo ... >> ${CMDPIPE}` again.

To work it around, you can open the FIFO (named pipe) in non-blocking mode:

```
set cpipe [open "$::env(CMDPIPE)" {RDONLY NONBLOCK} ]
```

This is also mentioned in [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> A  process  can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening for read-only will succeed even if no one has opened on the write side yet ...

The following is the simplified version of your code and it works fine for me (tested on **Debian 9.6**).

```
spawn bash --norc
set timeout -1

expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}
send "PS1='P''rompt: '\r"
#         ^^^^
expect "Prompt: "

proc do { cmd } {
    send "$cmd\r"
    if { $cmd == "exit" } {
        expect eof
        exit
    } else {
        expect "Prompt: "
    }
}

proc read_command {} {
    global cpipe
    if {[gets $cpipe cmd] < 0} {
        close $cpipe
        set cpipe [open cpipe {RDONLY NONBLOCK} ]
        fileevent $cpipe readable read_command
    } else {
        do $cmd
    }
}

set cpipe [open cpipe {RDONLY NONBLOCK} ]
fileevent $cpipe readable read_command
vwait forever
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately behavior is the same. Please note that I was setting non-blocking mode already with "fconfigure $cpipe -blocking 0". Still even with your way of opening the pipe nothing changes.

Comment: I should add that if you copy-paste the example into a couple of bash terminals you will see that the [  puts "Got command: $cmd" ] statement is called immediately after you run echo to send a command. So the read-readiness seems fine. It's just the output of the actual command missing. This seems to me like it's a buffering problem, or something to do with an event loop in Tcl and/or expect which I am unaware of (don't know much tcl).

Comment: i tried it myself and it worked fine for me. it's `open` which blocks so `fconfigure -blocking 0` would not help here.

Comment: This is the change that fixes it: send "PS1='P''rompt: '\r"

Comment: So, open has nothing to do with it. I do want it to block until someone connects to the pipe. What was happening is that the expect buffer was matching "Prompt: " on the INPUT portion of the command, thus getting stuck and not dumping the rest of the buffer. So: "Prompt: ls\r\nFILENAME1 FILENAME2\r\nPrompt: " would match the first occurrence (before ls is typed) and lag behind. Changing that to expect "Prompt: $" fixes my code as well (no need for NONBLOCK on open).

Comment: If you edit / type-up a clean answer, I will accept it.

Comment: double confirmed and `send "PS1='P''rompt: '\r"` alone does not fix for me. i still need open with NONBLOCK. commands like `echo pwd >> pipe` would work for most of the time because `pwd` is bash's builtin command which takes no time to execute. it's about timing. u can test with `echo 'sleep 1; pwd' >> pipe`.

Comment: I wonder if system has something to do with different behavior. Maybe bash/expect/tcl (or flavor of unix) has something to do with it. either way, for me it works with the prompt change and open as it was originally...

Comment: FYI, I see the same behavior as you on Ubuntu. Updating my Cygwin which was 1.7-based replicated the same on my Windows box. So indeed there were 2 issues and you addressed both.